# Light setup bash script for an ubuntu server

Tags: bash, server

I'm trying to create a setup script for our projects in an ubuntu server. This is what I have now, but I don't know if its correct, or can I do it differently/better ? If someone could take a look pls. Thanks

````bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e


# ================== 
# Step Functions
# ==================

# create_user() {
#   echo "
# ----------------------
#   1. Creating a new user with name `<user>` and gives correct access.
# ----------------------
# "
#  # [ASK]: How to make <user> a variable I read from STDIN
#  #        and  pass it around in the following commands

#   # add new user with the name of `user`
#   sudo "adduser --ingroup www-data --disabled-password $user"


#   # copy ssh/ folder from `ubuntu` user to new user 
#   # and gives the right permissions/privileges 
#   sudo cp -R ".ssh/" "/home/$user/"
#   sudo chown -R "$user:www-data" "/home/$user/.ssh/"
# }

function update_pkgs() {
  echo "
  ----------------------
    Prerequisites : Making sure everything is up to date
  ----------------------
  "
  # checks is all pkgs are up to date
  sudo apt-get update -y

  # installing necessary pkgs
  sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev -y
}


function installing_nginx() {
  echo "
  ----------------------
    3. Installing Nginx...
  ----------------------
  "
  sudo apt update
  sudo apt install nginx
  sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'
}


function installing_node() {
  echo "
  ----------------------
    4. Installing NVM & Node
  ----------------------
  "
  # install nvm
  curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash

  # verifies installation
  nvm --version

  # install node the latest stable version
  nvm install stable

}


function installing_yarn() {
  echo "
----------------------
  6. Installing Yarn
----------------------
"

  # updating pakages
  sudo apt-get update

  # installs yarn
  sudo apt-get install yarn

  # checks yarn version
  which yarn
  yarn --version
}

function installing_pm2() {
  echo "
  ----------------------
    7. Installing PM2 via YARN
  ----------------------
  "

  # install pm2 with npm
  yarn global add pm2

  # set pm2 to start automatically on system startup
  pm2 startup systemd
}


function parting_words(){
  echo "
  ----------------------
    Things left to Do

    1. Clone the repositories from devtools
    2. Add the ssh keys of developers to the .ssh/ folder
    3. Configure nginx
    4. Install cerbot for nginx and generate certificates
    5. Make sure everything is working correctly
    6. Delete user ubuntu
    7. Have a cup of coffee
  ----------------------
  "
}




# ================== 
# MAIN SCRIPT
# ==================

echo "
----------------------
  Server Setup Bash Script 
----------------------
"

read -p "Do You Wish to run this Script ? " -n 1 -r
echo
if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Yy]$ ]]
then
update_pkgs
echo "
----------------------
  Let's create a new user
----------------------
"
read -p "What should we call the new user ?" user
sudo "adduser --ingroup www-data --disabled-password $user"
sudo cp -R ".ssh/" "/home/$user/"
sudo chown -R "$user:www-data" "/home/$user/.ssh/"
echo "$user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" >> "/etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users"
installing_nginx
installing_node
installing_yarn
installing_pm2
parting_words
fi
```
````

Comment: You might want to look into [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html). It has the advantage that any step that has already been done will not be run again.

Comment: Agreed, Ansible is the tool you need.